# Ext modules over different rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $I$ be an ideal of $A$. Suppose $M, N$ are $A$-modules such that $IM=IN=0$, meaning they are canonically $A/I$-modules as well. I want to compare $Ext^{q}_{A}(M, N)$ and $Ext^{q}_{A/I}(M, N)$.
I know that there are spectral sequences. For example $Ext^{q}_{A/I}(Tor^{A}_{p}(A/I, M), N)\implies Ext^{p+q}_{A}(M, N)$, so in particular we have $Ext^{q}_{A}(M, N)=Ext^{q}_{A/I}(M, N)$ whenever $A/I$ or $M$ is flat over $A$.

Does anyone know of any results in this direction? Also, more generally, I would be very grateful for any reference where comparisons between injective resolutions over $A$ and $A/I$ are discussed in more detail. Somehow I don't find these things in my standard homological algebra references (which doesn't mean much since I'm not very deep into the field)

Wikipedia states that if $P$ is an injective $A$-module then $Ann_{I}(P)$ is injective over $A/I$. I can see that. But again any further referneces to other results would be warmly welcomed.

many thanks

Comment: What kind of hypothesis are you thinking in (if any)? As you pointed if A/I is flat over A that spectral sequence collapses, but this is a very strong hypothesis (if A is noetherian local it is equivalent to I=0). You can relax this hypothesis and still obtain information from that spectral sequence. For instance if I has projective dimension 1, the spectral sequence is in fact a long exact sequence. The situation is worse if I is generated by a regular sequence of length >1, but still the E² term has a nice description and is bounded in the first grading, etc.

Comment: Also, what kind of information from the Ext modules are you interested in? If only vanishing, sometimes highest and lowest terms in the spectral sequence are relatively easy to handle only from the E² terms.

Comment: Thank you. Looking at the projective dimension of I is a good idea. Well I don't have anything concrete in mind. I was just thinking about the problem of comparing derived functors of modules over different rings.. Basically I was hoping there was some larger theory where problems like this are addressed.